# Alert doesn't appear when I click on the "Upload" button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to perform a simple javascript validation where when the user clicks on the submit button in the form, it will check if the file either a 'png' or 'gif' file type. If it is correct file type, then display the loading bar and upload the form. If the file type is incorrect, then show a n alert stating file type is incorrect but don't show the loading bar and do not upload the form.

Below is the code but it is not displaying an alert when I click on the "Upload" button. What do I need to do so that when the user clicks on the "Upload" button, if incorrect file type then alert appears and it doesn't upload file, if file type is correct then it displays loading bar and uploads file.

```
var sourceImageForm;

var $fileImage = $("<form action='imageupload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' target='upload_target' onsubmit='startImageUpload(this);' class='imageuploadform' >" + 
"<label> Image File: <input name='fileImage' type='file' class='fileImage' /></label><br/>" +
"<input type='submit' name='submitImageBtn' class='sbtnimage' value='Upload' /></label></form>");

function startImageUpload(imageuploadform){

    $(".imageFile").change(function() {

    var val = $(this).val();

    switch(val.substring(val.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase()){
        case 'gif': case 'jpg': case 'png':
        return true;
            break;
        default:
            $(this).val('');
            alert("not an image");
            return false;
            break;
    }
});

  $(imageuploadform).find('.imagef1_upload_process').css('visibility','visible');
  $(imageuploadform).find('.imagef1_upload_form').css('visibility','hidden');
  sourceImageForm = imageuploadform;

      return true;
}
```

Comment: The syntax highlighter tells the story... Closing quote missing after `</form>`

Comment: Sorry that missing quotation isn't missing in my application, I must of accidentally deleted it when posting it in this question but there is no missing quotation. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the closing `"` in the third line, that may be the reason.

Comment: Sorry that missing quotation isn't missing in my application, I must of accidentally deleted it when posting it in this question but there is no missing quotation. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You are not preventing the form default behaviour, so when you submit it, it just go, it doesn't care about the javascript side.

```
$('form').submit(function(ev) {
// do your stuff here and return true to submit it or false to stop it
})
```

EDITED: Sorry you do bind on submit, but all you do when submit is press is bind the image element on change, you don't actually check anything on submit

Comment: Have I misplaced the code somewhere then or what do I need to do so that it checks the validation on submit?